# Error importing Theano in Windows

Tags: python, theano

I keep getting the error below when I try to import theano. I have mingw, libpython installed. I even tried installing TDM-GCC and adding that to path.

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
"C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSI
ON -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Users\Ganesh Anand\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\co
re\include" -I"C:\Users\Ganesh Anand\Anaconda2\include" -I"C:\Users\Ganesh Anand
\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev4-py2.7.egg\theano\gof" -L"C:\Users
\Ganesh Anand\Anaconda2\libs" -L"C:\Users\Ganesh Anand\Anaconda2" -o C:\Users\Ga
nesh Anand\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6
_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:
\Users\Ganesh Anand\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64
_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpy
thon27
g++.exe: error: Anand\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel
64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker
_ext.pyd: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: C:\Users\Ganesh: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Anand\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel
64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp: N
o such file or directory
```

It looks like the command is splitting my username and that is causing the problem but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Check this https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13973/a-few-tips-to-install-theano-on-windows-64-bits?limit=all

Comment: I was able to fix the above problem only by doing pip install keras theano, instead of using the latest version by pulling the code from Github. The Kaggle link was helpful for other errors I got afterwards.